# Disable text prediction on samsung Keybord

Tags: android, textedit, samsung-galaxy

i have a textedit field in my android app, this text field is intended for a serial key so text should not be autocompleted.

i managed to solve it on the stock android keyboard but the samsung keyboard is still showing suggestions and autocompleting no matter what flags i set, these are my current flags:

```
 android:inputType="textFilter|textNoSuggestions|textCapCharacters|textVisiblePassword"
```

i have also tried with

```
android:privateImeOptions="nm"
```

so, any other idea on how to programmatically disable this?

Comment: There is no requirement for any input method editor to honor anything in `android:inputType`. You are hinting at behavior that you want, but that is it. An IME can do whatever it wants, including showing suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it seems to me that some flags don't play nicely together in the samsung keyboard if i drop the `textFilter` flag just to leave

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textCapCharacters|textVisiblePassword"
```

it works as intended but if `textFilter` is added to `inputType` it will ignore the rest

Comment: This saved my bacon today! The most important point here is that `textFilter` prevents supressing the suggestions!

Answer (score 3):

> managed to solve it on the stock android keyboard but the samsung keyboard is still showing suggestions

The `textNoSuggestions` flag is just for this and no additional trickery should be required. If it'd be then something is broken here. Nonetheless I'd definitely try to avoid doing anything special for one particular IME.

Also [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) read:

> textNoSuggestions
>
> Can be combined with text and its variations to indicate that the IME
>   **should** not show any dictionary-based word suggestions.

The word "should" is a key here, so it's basically up to IME to honor your request and you may not be able to do a thing.

BTW: if it also ignores `textVisiblePassword` and shows dictionary for passwords then it is not a good keyboard. I'd not be surprised if it adds passwords to dictionary too :)

Comment: i'm with you on the bug aspect, if i drop textFilter it works, so im thinking its a bug that triggers when you feed in an unsupported flag or something